# Complexity of Deque implementation

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, time-complexity, deque

I was asked to implement a deque in a programming course using two vectors (frontVector and backVector), which should contain half of the data of the deque. However, my implementation seems to be taking so much runtime. Here is the template with all functions included.

```
template <typename T>
MyDeque<T>::MyDeque() {}

template <typename T>
MyDeque<T>::MyDeque(int n) : frontVector(n/2), backVector(n/2 + n%2) {}

template <typename T>
MyDeque<T>::MyDeque(std::initializer_list<T> vals) : frontVector(), backVector(int(vals.size())) {
    int i = 0;
    for (const auto& item : vals) {
        backVector[i++]=item;
    }
    balanceVectors();
}

template <typename T>
void MyDeque<T>::push_back(T val) {
    backVector.push_back(val);
    balanceVectors();
}

template <typename T>
void MyDeque<T>::push_front(T val) {
    frontVector.insert(frontVector.begin(),val);
    balanceVectors();
}

template <typename T>
void MyDeque<T>::pop_back() {
    if (!backVector.empty()) {
        backVector.pop_back();
        balanceVectors();
    }
    else if (!frontVector.empty()) {
        frontVector.pop_back();
        balanceVectors();
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MyDeque<T>::pop_front() {
    if (!frontVector.empty()) {
        frontVector.erase(frontVector.begin());
        balanceVectors();
    }
    else if (!backVector.empty()) {
        backVector.pop_back();
        balanceVectors();
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& MyDeque<T>::back() {
    if (!backVector.empty()) {
        return backVector.back();
    }
    return frontVector.front();
}

template <typename T>
const T& MyDeque<T>::back() const {
    if (!backVector.empty()) {
        return backVector.back();
    }
    return frontVector.front();
}

template <typename T>
T& MyDeque<T>::front() {
    if (!frontVector.empty()) {
        return frontVector.front();
    }
    return backVector.back();
}

template <typename T>
const T& MyDeque<T>::front() const {
    if (!frontVector.empty()) {
        return frontVector.back();
    }
    return backVector.front();
}

template <typename T>
bool MyDeque<T>::empty() const {
  return frontVector.empty() && backVector.empty();
}

template <typename T>
int MyDeque<T>::size() const {
  return int(frontVector.size()) + int(backVector.size());
}

template <typename T>
T& MyDeque<T>::operator[](int i) {
    if (i < static_cast<int>(frontVector.size())) {
        return frontVector[i];
    } 
    else {
        return backVector[i - frontVector.size()];
    }
}

template <typename T>
const T& MyDeque<T>::operator[](int i) const {
    if (i < static_cast<int>(frontVector.size())) {
        return frontVector[i];
    } 
    else {
        return backVector[i - frontVector.size()];
    }
}


template <typename T>
void MyDeque<T>::balanceVectors() {
    if (backVector.size() > frontVector.size() + 1) {
        frontVector.push_back(backVector.front());
        backVector.erase(backVector.begin());
    } 
    else if (frontVector.size() > backVector.size() + 1) {
        backVector.insert(backVector.begin(), frontVector.back());
        frontVector.pop_back();
    }
}

template class MyDeque<int>;
template class MyDeque<double>;
template class MyDeque<char>;
template class MyDeque<std::string>;
```

I think that this complexity is because of the balanceVectors() function, which requires removing and inserting elements from the beginning of both vectors. However, I am not sure how can this be implemented using amortized constant time. Any help in decreasing the complexity will be appreciated.

Comment: is it possible that you can reverse one of the vectors? and, do they really NEED to be balanced all of the time?

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code to really see what is the hot path?

Comment: Erasing/Inserting at the beginning of `std::vector` is O(N)`, perhaps just treat `backVector` as reversed as @user253751 suggests.

Comment: I am trying to reverse the frontVector. But in balancing I will need to insert at front too.

Comment: Also, if I reversed the backVector, I will be erasing from its beginning when pop_back() is called.

Comment: Implementing a deque with `insert` provides little functional advantage over a vector.  I would suggest the `front` vector stores the items in reverse order, so `front` would be the _last_ item.  Plus you should probably only balance the vectors when popping an item.  I would ask your tutor why it is necessary to keep the two vectors balanced when pushing items.

Comment: When balancing, it would be better to batch-move the items instead of processing them individually.  Also use `reserve` in the vectors to minimise memory allocations.

Comment: Ok I have done it with the frontVector reversed. However, consider this case:
deque{1,2,3,4,5}. frontVector is {2,1} and backVector is {3,4,5}. When I push_back an element to the deque (let's say 6), backVector will be {3,4,5,6} and needs rebalance. To rebalance, I need to insert the element "3" at the beginning of frontVector and then erase it from the beginning of backVector, which is still costly.

Comment: How can I batch move them? you mean like create new vectors and then copy to backVector and frontVector?

Comment: Batching would only be possible if you balanced upon pop.  When you balance after pushing every item then batching is not feasible.  The scheme doesn't really make sense TBH.  The only other thing I can think of would be to implement circular buffers, so vector[0] is not necessarily the first item.  Then you avoid having to slice the vector.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point. What to do when I push a new item?

Comment: Rebalancing is costly. You should only do it when the side you are popping from is empty.

Comment: I'm a teacher that would potentially give this assignment. What theory have you've been given before this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

- Since you can only efficiently push to the end of a vector, you need
  to represent the front part of the deque in reverse order
  relative to the deque so that when you push to the front internally you are
  pushing to the back of a vector.
- Since rebalancing involves O(n) copying you should not rebalance unless you have to. Never rebalance after pushing. Only rebalance before you would have to pop from either the front vector or the back vector but can't because it is empty.

Also note that there is a symmetry to the rebalancing logic such that you rebalance by doing one copy with a reverse iterator and one copy with a forward iterator when rebalancing from front to back or from back to front.

[Here is some example code if you need it.](https://godbolt.org/z/61x8aTWrT)